# MsgBox after not finding a value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that runs an `InputBox` in which user types number and then excel finds a cell in a certain range which contains that value. I'd like to make an `MsgBox` which would make an alert if given number is not found and run `InputBox` again until the value is in range.

I have kinda idea how do I do it, but can't make the finding itself work. I've recorded a macro but don't know how to set it properly if it doesn't find anything.

My code so far:

```
Sub leftbutton()

Start: n = InputBox("Podaj numer punktu z wykresu") 'give me a point number from a chart
If n = "" Then Exit Sub
If n = "0" Then
MsgBox ("Liczba musi byc wieksza od zera") 'number must be > 0
GoTo Start
End If
If Not IsNumeric(n) Then
MsgBox ("Podaj liczbe!") 'give me a number!
GoTo Start
End If


Range("AS3:AS50000").Select
if
    Selection.Find(What:=n, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase _
    :=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate     'now how to know if it finds value or not?

Then msgbox("Nie ma takiego punktu na wykresie") 'there's no such point on a chart
Goto Start
Else '~> select cell with the found value
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below will check in your range you specified and either give you error if nothing is found or row number of cell with match.

```
Dim FindResult As Object

    n=... 'set whatever value you want to find

    Range("AS3:AS50000").Select
    Set FindResult = Selection.Find(n, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If FindResult Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("missing")
    Else
        MsgBox (FindResult.Row)
    End If
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! I was quite close with my thinking though, nice.